# From numpy array within array to single row

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I am preprocessing my data to make this work:

```
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X, Y)
```

I am struggling to reshape my numpy.ndarray.

At this point, for Y I have:

```
Y
array([array([[52593.4410802]]), array([[52593.4410802]])], dtype=object)
Y.shape
(2,)
type(Y)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

And for X, I have:

```
X
array([array([[34.07824204],
       [33.36032467],
       [24.61158084],
       ...,
       [34.62648953],
       [34.49591937],
       [34.40951467]]),
       array([[ 4.50136316],
       [ 7.46307729],
       [17.07135805],
       ...,
       [57.98715047],
       [54.5733181 ],
       [50.13691107]])], dtype=object)
X.shape
(2,)
type(X)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

I would like to get my X and transform so each data becomes a column/feature (idea of transpose). So each value would became a feature something like this idea:

```
X[0][0]
array([34.07824204])
X[0][1]
array([33.36032467])
# Sudo code idea:
# X_new = [0][0],[0][1],...
# X_new = append(X_new,[1][0],[1][1]...)
```

What I have tried:

```
nsamples, nx, ny = X.shape
d2_train_dataset = X.reshape((nsamples,nx*ny))
```

Also, I tried to reshape and transpose but it will not give what I need:

```
X
array([array([[34.07824204],
       [33.36032467],
       [24.61158084],
       ...,
       [34.62648953],
       [34.49591937],
       [34.40951467]]),
       array([[ 4.50136316],
       [ 7.46307729],
       [17.07135805],
       ...,
       [57.98715047],
       [54.5733181 ],
       [50.13691107]])], dtype=object)
X.T
array([array([[34.07824204],
       [33.36032467],
       [24.61158084],
       ...,
       [34.62648953],
       [34.49591937],
       [34.40951467]]),
       array([[ 4.50136316],
       [ 7.46307729],
       [17.07135805],
       ...,
       [57.98715047],
       [54.5733181 ],
       [50.13691107]])], dtype=object)
```

As suggested in one of the comments, I tried, without sucess to:
(I get the output as input)

```
X.flatten()
array([array([[34.07824204],
       [33.36032467],
       [24.61158084],
       ...,
       [34.62648953],
       [34.49591937],
       [34.40951467]]),
       array([[ 4.50136316],
       [ 7.46307729],
       [17.07135805],
       ...,
       [57.98715047],
       [54.5733181 ],
       [50.13691107]])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: You have arrays within arrays. You should do a `flatten()` first before `reshape()`. Bear in mind that reshape only works if the numbers match up. Eg. `50*1 == 5*5*2`

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand from `Y`, your labels are continuous, not discrete. Your data suggest that you need a regression model, but you are trying to fit a binary classifier, logistic regression. As a regression algorithm, you may use [linear regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html), [Support Vector Regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html) or any other regression model.

Answer (score 0):

Before reshaping, get rid of your arrays in arrays.
You can do this easily with `numpy.stack`. For instance

```py
import numpy
from numpy import array
Y = array([array([[52593.4410802]]), array([[52593.4410802]])], dtype=object)
Y = numpy.stack(Y)
print(Y.shape)
print(Y)
```

gives:
*(2,1,1)*
*[[[52593.4410802]]*

*[[52593.4410802]]]*

From this, you can reshape to what you need.